# How to access public_path() in a php file Laravel public folder

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a php file in laravel public folder and I want to know how would I access the public folder, Like in other files we could do something like this  public_path() to access the public path. What can we do in the php file in  public folder to access the public path ? Please assist.

Comment: Why do you have a php file in the public folder?

Comment: public_path() is the path to the public folder. You can use this for CSS / JS / Imagery etc (you shouldn't have any php files in there apart from the index.php (by default))

Comment: if you are using Laravel you should follow MVC

Comment: `__DIR__` will reference the path to the folder in which a script is stored.